# Bedeutungsnuance zwischen "sich verlieren in + Dativ" und "sich verlieren in + Akkusativ"?

Tags: grammatical-case

Bis jetzt ging ich davon aus, man würde den Akkusativ oder den Dativ verwenden je nachdem, ob das Subjekt schon am Anfang innerhalb des Rahmens der Präpositional-Ergänzung war. Wenn diese erste Annahme richtig ist, dann sollte man beides sagen dürfen:

1. *Sie verlor sich in den Wald* (= Sie war woanders, ging in den Wald
   hinein und merkte, sie konnte den Weg nicht zurückfinden)
2. *Sie verlor sich im Wald* (= Sie war im Wald, bewegte sich
   innerhalb des Waldes und merkte, sie konnte den Weg nicht
   zurückfinden)

Heute habe ich aber gelesen:
"[Bei der Pressekonferenz] hatte der Premier noch mehr frohe Botschaften zu verkünden. [...] Doch als die Journalisten konkret nachfragten, verlor sich der Konservative im Ungefähren."

https://www.welt.de/politik/ausland/plus206703033/Umgang-mit-dem-Coronavirus-Das-britische-Hochrisiko-Experiment.html

Weil der Verfasser die früheren Botschaften des Politikers erwähnt und wegen des "doch"s, nehme ich an, der Verfasser bezeichnet das früher Gesagte nicht als "ungefähr". Metaphorisch betrachtet war der Politiker also im Präzisen und dann fand er sich im Unpräzisen bzw. im Ungefähren.

Wenn beide Annahmen richtig sind, dann würde ich "er verlor sich ins Ungefähre" erwarten. Doch wurde der Dativ verwendet.
Meine Frage ist also:

- Wäre es überhaupt möglich, in diesem Kontext "er verlor sich ins
  Ungefähre" zu sagen?
- Wenn möglich, gäbe es einen Bedeutungsunterschied mit dem
  ursprünglichen Satz mit Dativ?
- Spielt es irgendeine Rolle, dass hier nach der Präposition ein
  substantiviertes Adjektiv steht? Wie wäre es z. B. mit "Er verlor
  sich in utopischen Plänen" vs. "Er verlor sich in utopische Pläne"?

Comment: Das "Doch als die" bezieht sich darauf, dass mit der Verkündung der frohen Botschaften bei den Journalisten die Erwartung gesetzt wurde, dass es präzise Details geben wird. ... Doch die Erwartungen wurden enttäuscht - also nicht das früher gesagt war (kausal) präzise, sondern die früher geäußerte Ankündigung ließ vermuten, dass was Präzises folgt. Die OPtion `ins Ungefähre` halte ich für sprachlich "ausreichend iO" - doch Grammatikregeln kann ich keine bieten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duden.de listet verschiedene Varianten für "sich verlieren". Dabei werden Bedeutuungen unterschieden (allmählich schwächer werden vs. sich verirren), aber Dativ und Akkusativ werden offenbar gemischt.

> Der Weg verliert sich **im Nebel**
>
> Die Strasse verlor sich **in dunstige Ferne**

"verirren":

> **in unsere öde Gegend** verliert sich selten jemand

Hier Akkusativ - wohin.

(vgl. **In unserer übersichtlichen** Landschaft kann man sich gar nicht verlieren / verloren gehen)

"vom wesentlichen abschweifen":

> der Autor verliert sich **in Detailschilderungen**

Akk. o. Dativ??? Sehr praktisch!

---

> Ich habe mich **in den Wald** verloren

Damit will man aussagen, dass man unbemerkt in den Wald hineingeraten ist. Das wäre die Antwort auf: du weisst doch, dass du nicht alleine in den Wald gehen darfst.

Das ist aber eine ziemliche Ausrede, denn normalerweise gibt es eine klare Grenze, und keine Buschlandschaft als unmerklichen Übergang.

---

Der Koservative, der sich im Ungefähren verliert, schient mir genau richtig. Es ist eben keine geplante ***Flucht ins Ungefähre***. Er wurde von hartnäckigen Fragen dorthin getrieben --- und fand dann nicht mehr zurück.

---

> Er verlor sich in utopischen Plänen
>
> Er verlor sich in utopische Pläne

Die erste Variante schient mir normal - da hat jemand Mühe mit seinen Plänen, weil sie utopisch sind. Evtl. macht er das bewusst und mit Freude.

Die zweite tönt dramatischer: jemand hat den Bezug zur Realität verloren.

---

Eine Spur verliert sich auch **im Fluss**, und nicht **in den Fluss**.